# Choosing what columns to show in PHP from my sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic select * from displaying my table on my page.  I want the option to show just the columns someone may choose from the page.  Is this possible?

Its a basic table with 16 columns.  Not everytime is someone going to want every column shown.  Say they only want the columns a-e shown.  Whats the best way to have them select those columns and have it build the query.

Either that or have dropwons in the Table Headers to filter on.  Like if you added a filter to Excel.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some more detail to your question because the obvious answer is just specify the columns instead of using `*`.

Comment: Never (almost never) use SELECT * it's a common source of problems.

Comment: @tharkun, other than the fact that `select *` is a bit slower, what problems do you mean?

Comment: @Byron, `SELECT *` causes headaches later when you do not define your columns, and rather 'expect' them to be there, if they are ever modified your query fails, causing headaches for someone who is troubleshooting.  `SELECT *` works for a test, but for final code it should clearly define the columns.

Comment: SELECT * is bad coding practice (code smell) because a) you can not foresee what changes will happen to your table. Selecting distinct columns makes sure your query doesn't break if you insert a new column. b) your code is easier to read, much easier indeed, if you select distinct columns. c) it will most often not be the case, that you need the whole data row, why should you query for columns you don't need. ... etc.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be to output your 'data table' into something that is modified by say JAVASCRIPT, using a library like jQuery, you can utilize a 'table plugin' that will let you hide/show columns, and reorder as you please.  Otherwise you would do this ordering via backend SQL query changes.

JAVASCRIPT method lets the user do the heavy lifting of hiding/showing/sorting data that you just supply in 1 format.

Here are some examples of plugins to achieve this JS approach:

- http://javabyexample.wisdomplug.com/web-programming/47-javascript/88-20-best-jquery-table-plugins.html
- http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-great-jquery-plugins-for-better-table-manipulation/

Enjoy!

Comment: this is one of my favourite solutions for this sort of problem

Comment: +1 I agree with @dnagirl; handling data's presentation separately from its retrieval is the way to go whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much of anything about your code or database, a simple approach would be:

Have the user specify columns (pick them from a list, for example), and then construct the SQL statement in code, concatenating the selected columns into the SELECT list instead of specifying *, and then executing the SQL statement.

Comment: I think this ^^ is probably the best solution for such a problem.

Comment: if you do this, it's really important to validate the user input so you don't get SQL injection attacks. Personally, I'd specify all the columns in my query, but output only the columns the user asked for.  Then you don't have to change your query and you don't have to worry about user input messing up your database.

Comment: @dnagirl Validating user input is an important point. Specifically in this example, I'm suggesting you allow a user to pick from a predefined set of columns, not simply enter their own values. As for always selecting the same columns and only displaying the chosen ones, that's a good call: the DB's query optimizer will likely have an easier time executing the same query than one with an arbitrary SELECT list (though I don't know how true that is in practice).

Comment: @djacobson: if the query cache is turned on, always using the same query will definitely be faster.

Comment: @dnagirl Agreed. I just wonder if you have a very simple SELECT query, e.g. `SELECT <some subset of T's 10 columns> FROM T`, if the optimizer will realize that the queries have essentially the same execution plan regardless of which columns you request. Be an interesting experiment...

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you mean by show.

You could add the columns instead of the * in the select, that way only the selected columns will be available in the returned list.

If that is not what you mean you need to add more detail as noted in the comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (adapt as necessary):


`` function show_column_selectors($available, $chosen, $labels){
 echo <<<HTML
<form method="POST" action="#">
HTML;
 foreach($available as $column){
  $id = 'show_'.$column;
  $checked = in_array($column, $chosen) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';

  // See how I write the input elements with the same name,
  //                                        ending said name with []?
  // This will make PHP join all their values in an array.
  //                                      (see main() function below)
  echo <<<HTML
<label for="{$id}">
<input id="{$id}" name="columns_to_show[]"
       type="checkbox" {$checked} value="{$column}">
{$labels[$column]}
</label>
HTML;
 }
 echo <<<HTML
 <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
HTML;
}

function do_query($cols){
 // This is boilerplate I hacked just to test this out. Ignore it
 $mysqli = mysqli_connect('server', 'username', 'password', 'database');
 if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
  die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '.$mysqli->connect_error);
 }

 // Here you build your query from the array $cols,
 //    which contains the columns chosen by the user.
 // See below, in the main() function, how it is obtained.
 $query = "SELECT `".implode("`, `", $cols)."` FROM `table`;";

 // More boilerplate follows
 $result = $mysqli->query($query, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
 $rows = array();
 if($result){
  while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc())){
   $rows []= $row;
  }
 }
 mysqli_free_result($result); 
 $mysqli->close();

 return $rows;
}

function show_result($columns, $rows){
 echo "<table><tr>\n";
 foreach($columns as $column){
  echo "<th>{$column}</th>\n";
 }
 echo "<tr>\n";
 foreach($rows as $row){
  echo "<tr>\n";
  foreach($columns as $column){
   echo "<td>{$row[$column]}</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>\n";
 }
 echo "</table>";
}



function main(){
 // This are the column names as seen by the database
 $AVAILABLE_COLUMNS = array(
  'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'
 );

 // And these map between the above
    //     and what you want the user to see
 $LABELS = array(
  'col1' => 'Column 1',
  'col2' => 'Column 2',
  'col3' => 'Column 3',
  'col4' => 'Column 4',
 );

 // This is the important part, where you obtain the array
 //                             with user's chosen columns.
 // NOTE: same name as the input elements, but with no []
 if(empty($_POST['columns_to_show'])){
  $chosen_columns = $AVAILABLE_COLUMNS;
 }
 else{
  $chosen_columns = array_intersect($_POST['columns_to_show'], $AVAILABLE_COLUMNS);
 }

 show_column_selectors($AVAILABLE_COLUMNS, $chosen_columns, $LABELS);
 $rows = do_query($chosen_columns);
 show_result($chosen_columns, $rows);
}

main();
?><html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
</body>
</html> ``

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using the [YUI Datatable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/) for this.  I use it often for similar applications.  You can query the server for specifically which columns are shown, or just return the whole set (inefficient though if the data isn't always needed).